# Query for Week Transaction

Tags: sql-server

I am currently creating a function that can return its week based on the date of the transaction table, but how can I apply the range wherein the date is:

If the first day of the month falls to Tuesday up to Saturday then

```
07/01/2020 - 07/12/2020 = Week 1,
07/13/2020 - 07/19/2020 = Week 2,
07/20/2020 - 07/26/2020 = Week 3,
07/27/2020 - 07/31/2020 = Week 4
```

and when the 1st day of the month falls on Monday or Sunday then the return should be

```
06/01/2020 - 06/07/2020 = Week 1,
06/08/2020 - 06/14/2020 = Week 2,
06/15/2020 - 06/21/2020 = Week 3,
06/22/2020 - 06/30/2020 = Week 4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `07/01/2020 - 07/12/2020 = Week 1`? That's a period of 11 days. Sounds like you need a Calendar Table.

Answer (score 0):

You are having different way of classifying week, based on the start day of the month.

you can go for below IF ELSE logic.

```sql
DECLARE @transactionDate date = '2020-07-12'
DECLARE @WeekName VARCHAR(30)

IF (datename(weekday,dateadd(day,1,EOMONTH(@transactionDate,-1)))) IN ('Sunday','Monday')
BEGIN
SET @WeekName = (SELECT  CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN 'Week 1'
            WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 13 AND 19 THEN 'Week 2'
             WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 20 AND 26 THEN 'Week 3'
             WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 27 AND 31 THEN 'Week 4' END )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @WeekName = (SELECT  CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN 'Week 1'
            WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN 'Week 2'
             WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN 'Week 3'
             WHEN DATEPART(day,@transactionDate) BETWEEN 22 AND 31 THEN 'Week 4' END 
             )
END 

SELECT @WeekName
```

> Week 2